# Drop up in a menu using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu bar where in for one of the list items I would like to get a drop up since we can fit in only a few icons there.For the last item when I click on it the drop up doesnt seems to work . What should i be doing here.

Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/snt/16y2ckjf/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbarBottom" class="navbarwrapper ">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            
<li class="dropdown-toggle dropup"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="mylocation">
                            <span class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="getdistance" >
                            <span class="fa fa-exchange fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="annotationtool">
                            <span class="fa fa-font fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="annotationtool">
                            <span class="fa fa-font fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
             </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to include the bootstrap JS and jQuery. Seems to work if you add those.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="navbarBottom" class="navbarwrapper ">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            
<li class="dropdown-toggle dropup">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="mylocation">
                            <span class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="getdistance" >
                            <span class="fa fa-exchange fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="annotationtool">
                            <span class="fa fa-font fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="annotationtool">
                            <span class="fa fa-font fa-inverse"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></span></a>
            </li>
            
             </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad I forgot. But the thing is I want these to go up as a drop up and now drop down.

Comment: @SNT oh you literally want the menu to go up, not down? Is this a vertical only menu? What should happen to the menu items before the dropdown when the menu "drops up"?

Comment: Its a vertical menu where in if the last item is been clicked on the list ( of four items)under should go up as a drop up. The first three items in the list  stay as they are.

Comment: @SNT I edited the code in my answer - is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Exactly . But then this doesnt seem to work when its a vertical bar.

Comment: @SNT do you mean horizontal? Where do you want the menu to go if it's horizontal? Now it's at the top of the screen, if the menu goes "up" then it will go off screen. And the menu doesn't work at all in your fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133106/discussion-between-snt-and-michael-coker).

Comment: Need to get a cup of coffee !!? This is actually a horizontal bar which comes at the bottom of the phone. Since we cannot accommodate many icons there I am trying to use a drop up for the last list item.

Comment: re: chat, no thanks. re: "Need to get a cup of coffee !!?" is that directed at me? If you position the menu to be at the bottom of the page, if the menu is vertical, the submenu drops "up" above the button you clicked. If the menu is horizontal, the menu drops "up" above the menu, but the menu background is white, you would just need to add a background to that menu to see the items.